# How to add a class in the MATLAB path

Tags: matlab, class, oop, matlab-class

I have 2 classes in folder :

- C:\controller\functions\VerifyModel.m
- C:\OGVD\prod\KMLP\controller\controllerStatus.m

#### VerifyModel.m

```
classdef verifyModel < matlab.unittest.TestCase
    methods(access=public)
        function...
    end
end
```

#### controllerStatus.m

```
classdef controllerStatus < verifyModel
    .....
end
```

but when I run `controllerStatus.m`, I got an error as the class I used isn't in the path.
I've tried by adding `C:\controller\functions\@VerifyModel\VerifyModel.m`

What I could do so that the class is added in the path?

Comment: You have not said if that folder is on your path. Not the @ folder of course, as it MUST not be so. Nor have you told us if you have tried a "clear classes" command. This is sometimes useful.

Comment: I think you should either make sure they are both in the same folder OR you could add one of the two as a function within the other class?

Comment: my problem is that the class isn't on the matlab path serach , I don't want to use addpath(...) but added VerifyModel.m in @VerifyModel folder and from the second class inherit VerifyModel

Comment: Why don't you want to use addpath?  addpath is the correct matlab function for what you are trying to do.